# What are MySQL limits, how much can it store?

Tags: mysql

I wasn't able to find any helpful link so I am asking you guys.

What are the limits of mysql? How many queries can it do at the same time?

I want to save chat logs in database along with other account history, so, how often should I clear it?

Comment: Facebook uses MySQL. Will you be storing more data than Facebook?

Comment: It's all dependent on your hardware and architecture so your not going to find an answer to this question.

Comment: @Strawberry I *believe* Facebook rewrote the SQL structure and customised it for their needs, so it's not the same out-the-box code that everyone else uses

Comment: @Martin You can see where I'm going though.

Comment: @Strawberry yes, :) but I wouldn't want Mister Knuckles to roll out a brand new Social Networking site and expect it to work perfectly for 1billion users on a finely tuned standard SQL install......

Answer (score 7):

> How many queries can it do at the same time?

That depends on what you mean by a query, and what you mean by "at the same time."

In my experience, a single well-tuned MySQL server can execute over 10,000 queries per second, if they are simple queries.

But queries per second is not the same as "at the same time" because many queries take only a tiny fraction of a second. You might see a peak concurrency of only a few hundred queries, even if you have a throughput of 10,000 qps.

To get greater scalability, most sites use multiple MySQL servers instead of expecting one server to keep handling increasing traffic. For example Wikipedia runs 25,000 queries per second, spread over 20 servers. https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/case-studies/mysql-cs-wikipedia.html

In some benchmarks with high-end servers, it has been proven to run over 1 million queries per second. https://www.flamingspork.com/blog/2014/06/03/1-million-sql-queries-per-second-mysql-5-7-on-power8/

The MySQL manual has this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limits.html which covers architectural limits like table size.

In the system I manage, our largest table is over 5 billion rows. It takes some care to index and partition this table, and we have to be careful how we query it.

We have many other tables that each have over 100 million rows. These are much easier to manage and query. No partitioning is needed in these tables.

Your server capacity is important too. More RAM, more CPU cores, fast disks are all important to the performance of a database server. You can get a lot of scalability, but it costs a lot.

Ultimately, you really need to know how much can you do with the server you can afford, under your application's workload? That's not something that anyone here on Stack Overflow can answer for you. You have to test it yourself.